# .NET "default line terminator"?

Tags: .net, text, newline

Is there any way to figure out what .NET is using as its "default line terminator"?  For example, documentation for StringBuilder.AppendLine(String) says it "Appends a copy of the specified string followed by the default line terminator...".  Several text-related classes in .NET refer to the same concept.

Is there any way to programmatically figure out what is being used as the line terminator (at runtime)?  Or is it safe to assume that it will always be "\r\n" for a Windows machine?  I'd rather not hard-code that value into my code if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[`StringBuilder.AppendLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx) will use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx), which is "`\r\n`" for non-Unix platforms and "`\n`" for Unix platforms.

It will always be "`\r\n`" for a Windows machine, but you can use `Environment.NewLine` in lieu of a hard-coded value.

*thanks to @Guffa for verifying this*

Comment: Ah perfect, I knew there must be something like that.  Thanks!

Comment: wish there was a way to change the default line terminator for a particular StringBuilder object

Answer (score 21):

This is the code from the `StringBuilder.AppendLine(string)` method (using .NET Reflector):

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public StringBuilder AppendLine(string value)
{
   this.Append(value);
   return this.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

As you see, it's indeed using the `Environment.NewLine` property.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, the newline was '\r' that is until they based their OS on linux. Now its '\n'.

Comment: Just a minor nit-pick: today's Mac OS is actually based on UNIX, not linux. And the first UNIX-based version came our in early 2001, about a year before .NET was released. So the '\r' notation has not been relevant for some time.