# Create linux shell script files in C# (which does not need dos2unix )

Tags: c#, linux, shell, portability, eol

I use C# to create shell scripts to automate my tasks in Linux.
In order to do this, I use below structure:

```
List<string> batchFileLines = new List<string>();
batchFileLines.Add("shell command 1");
batchFileLines.Add("shell command 2");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(shellBatchFileName, batchFileLines.ToArray());
```

However when I move my file to linux due to EOL difference in windows and linux ([which a fixed suggested here for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369113/1080355)), EOLs in shell file need to be corrected with `dos2unix` command.
I want to know how can I manipulate my file in C# so it is not required to execute `dos2unix`.

What would be the way to replace new lines with linux format with minimum effort?

Comment: You could just append ascii 10 at the end of each line.

Comment: @rory.ap DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").,  so I think I should remove '\r'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Unix style text file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841761/writing-unix-style-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988427/1080355), I should change

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(shellBatchFileName, batchFileLines.ToArray());
```

to

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(shellBatchFileName, string.Join("\n", batchFileLines.ToArray()));
```

The output file will not require `dos2unix` anymore.